# Ubuntu on Huawei MateBook X Pro: NVIDIA is not recognized

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution

I am trying to install the latest version of Nvidia driver, but Ubuntu does not recognize my NVIDIA GeForce MX150 graphics.

I follow all these steps but did not work:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Comment: Have you tried just installing the 390 driver itself?  Ubuntu 16.04 or older `sudo apt install nvidia-390` or if Ubuntu 18.04 or newer `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390`

Comment: Just by searching ["ubuntu huawei mate book x pro" on DDG](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ubuntu+huawei+mate+book+x+pro&t=canonical&ia=web), there seems to be many relevant articles and reviews to check.

Comment: i'was tryed with all 390,384,410,396 none has worked